# pass variable to php page using ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

index.html

```
<?php
while($admin_data=mysql_fetch_row($query2)){
    ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $admin_data[0];?></td>
<td><?php echo $admin_data[1];?></td>
<td><?php echo $admin_data[2];?></td>
<td><?php echo $admin_data[3];?></td>
<td><a href="javascript:void()" id="delete">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<div id="result_delete"></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

jquery file

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        $("#result_delete").load("delete.php");
    });
    });
    </script>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include "db/db.php";
if($_GET['drop']){
$drop=$_GET['drop'];
}
echo $drop;
?>
```

how to pass value to delete.php page.
i want to pass a variable to url
thanks for your answers

Comment: Your HTML will have multiple elements, all with an `id` of delete.

Comment: thanks for comment.i got the solution  by changing id to class.

Comment: i also want to know .that how to send variable of particular anchor

Answer (score 4):

IDS are SINGULAR they can not repeat. Use a class.

```
<td><a href="javascript:void()" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
```

and

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
```

better yet

```
$("#tableId").on("click", ".delete", function(){
```

And hopefully the `<div id="result_delete"></div>` does not live right after the TR since that is invalid HTML markup.

---

Since you can not figure out how to get the id, it is simple.

```
$("#tableId").on("#click", ".delete")function(){
    var val = encodeURIComponent($(this).data("val"));
    $("#result_delete").load("delete.php?drop=" + val);
});
```

Doing a delete request with a get request is a bad idea

Comment: its working fine..so nice of you ..thanks alot :) :)

Comment: i also want to know .that how to send variable of particular anchor

Comment: What variable... Use a data attribute `<a href="javascript:void()" data-val="1234" ../>` and use `$(this).data("val")`

Comment: where to add $(this).data("val")

Comment: It is best practice here not to keep updating questions with more requirements. Make new questions. What do you not understand, get the value inside the onclick, use it. `function() { var myVal = $(this).data("val"); alert(myVal); }`

Comment: sorry sir..but i want to pass variable to delete.php page.
please check the question again..i updated delete.php page as well thanks

Comment: Do you not know how to pass a value via a post or get with jQuery's ajax stuff? Look at the documentation for data.

Comment: i used = <a href="javascript:void() data-val=<?php echo $admin_data[1];?>" class="delete" id="<?php echo $admin_data[1];?>">Delete</a></td>

Comment: var a=$(this).attr("data-val");
$(".delete").click(function(){
 $(this).data("val")
 $("#result_delete").load("delete.php?drop=a");
 
 });
});